# argparse: Include default value and type in '--help'

Tags: python, argparse

Right now I'm using this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Run the Foo',
    formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
```

Which prints out the defaults as so:

```
--install-only        Do not run benchmark or verification, just install and
                      exit (default: False)
```

Is there a simple way to have this *also* print out the types, like this:

```
--install-only        Do not run benchmark or verification, just install and
                      exit (default: False) (type: Boolean)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your own `HelpFormatter` class, inspired by the ones included in `argparse.py`:

```
class DefaultsAndTypesHelpFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    def _get_help_string(self, action):
        help = action.help
        if '%(default)' not in action.help:
            if action.default is not argparse.SUPPRESS:
                defaulting_nargs = [argparse.OPTIONAL, argparse.ZERO_OR_MORE]
                if action.option_strings or action.nargs in defaulting_nargs:
                    help += ' (default: %(default)s)'
                if action.type:
                    help += ' (type: %(type)s)'
        return help
```

This will mostly do what you want, though do note that it doesn't print the type for `action='store_true'`.  I think that's OK, because `(default: False)` is pretty clear already, but if you want to be even more explicit you can add a clause like `if isinstance(action, argparse._StoreTrueAction)` and add whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

The `ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` just adds a `%(default)s` string to all of your argument help lines.  You could add that yourself.  And you can add a `%(type)s` string as well.

```
p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--install-only',type=int,help='default %(default)s, type %(type)s')
p.print_help()
```

producing:

```
usage: ipython [-h] [--install-only INSTALL_ONLY]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --install-only INSTALL_ONLY
                        default None, type int
```

Keep in mind, though, that `type` is usually a function like `int`, `float`, or `None` (which is the default 'string' type).  There isn't a `Boolean` `type` - unless you have written a function that converts a string to a True/False value.  For a `store_true` Action, the `type` is `None`.

The `action` parameter is usually a string, but that gets translated to an Action subclass, not an attribute of the Action itself.  Thus `%(action)s` will not work.

So while it is possible to display the `type` attribute in the help line, I think it has limited value.  You will have greater control by just including that information explicitly in the help string.